# Way to read Windows EventLog with Java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, event-log

Does anyone have any pointers on how to read the Windows EventLog without using JNI? Or if you *have to* use JNI, are there any good open-source libraries for doing so?

Answer (score 2):

JNA 3.2.8 has both an implementation for all event logging functions and a Java iterator. Read [this](http://code.dblock.org/ShowPost.aspx?id=125).

```
EventLogIterator iter = new EventLogIterator("Application");         
while(iter.hasNext()) { 
    EventLogRecord record = iter.next(); 
    System.out.println(record.getRecordId() 
            + ": Event ID: " + record.getEventId() 
            + ", Event Type: " + record.getType() 
            + ", Event Source: " + record.getSource()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/wellink/archive/2005/04/08/3289.aspx
and
http://www.j-interop.org/

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider looking at [J/Invoke](http://www.jinvoke.com/) or [JNA (Java Native Access)](https://github.com/twall/jna/) as an alternative to the much berated JNI.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).